# Updating laravel 6.0 from 5.8 error with symfony

Tags: laravel, symfony, composer-php

when I tried to update my laravel proyect from version 5.8 to 6.0 we received an error with simfony

Mi composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.1",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~6.0.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "picqer/php-barcode-generator": "^0.3.0",
        "pulkitjalan/geoip": "^4.0@dev",
        "tordek/afiphp": "^0.2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

And when i run composer update I received this error:

```
 [Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]
  Problem 1
      - Installation request for laravel/framework ^6.2 -> satisfiable by lar
  avel/framework[6.x-dev].
      - laravel/framework 6.x-dev requires symfony/console ^4.3.4 -> no match
  ing package found.
```

How can I repair it? Is posible do it in my project?

My file Composer.json is correct? Is posible update?

Comment: Did you follow the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#upgrade-6.0)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install symfony/console ^4.3.4
use command "composer require" to install

Comment: before run composer update, run composer require symfony/console?

Comment: On the other hand you can run "composer require symfony/console" from your terminal

Comment: I cant install symfony/console, I tried install with composer.json with Laravel 6.0 and with laravel 5.8, in both cases I cant install it.

Comment: When I install a new version of Laravel that use new components, they dont install automatically???